# JBoss application server 7 adapt to Red Hat

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, redhat, jboss7.x

We are using "JBoss application server 7.0.2" in our projects hosted in Ubuntu OS. We are planning to change the OS from "Ubuntu 20.04" to "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server". Will JBoss 7.0.2 application server adapt to Red Hat as JBoss version is very old? If "No" What would be the feasible solution.

We cannot migrate the JBoss 7.0.2 version as its dependency is high & critical, Which is in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know that Red Hat does not support JBoss AS.

On the other hand, Red Hat supports JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP). For your info, JBoss EAP is derived from the WildFly/JBoss AS community project.

Since you are planning to change OS to RHEL, I would suggest starting thinking of the JBoss EAP alternative.

Comment: Currently, we are using java version "1.7.0_80" + Jboss AS 7.0.2, Could you let me know
why RHEL doesn't support JBoss AS.

Also, let me know Which version of JBoss EAP supports java version 1.7.0_80.

Comment: Java 7 is only supported with JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP) 6.
For your reference, I have included below the JBoss EAP 6 versions and their equivalent JBoss AS / jboss.org versions: JBoss EAP 6.4 <-> JBoss AS 7.5, JBoss EAP 6.3 <-> JBoss AS 7.4, JBoss EAP 6.2 <-> JBoss AS 7.3, JBoss EAP 6.1 <-> JBoss AS 7.2, JBoss EAP 6.0 <-> JBoss AS 7.1.2

However, you have to know that EAP 6 has already reached the End of Maintenance and now requires an Extended Life Subscription for Support.